# React Hooks Update Nested Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an array of object named as options in the state using useState hook I just want to update a nested array object at a specific index.

```
var subOptionModel = {
        text: "test",
        price: 0,
    };
    var optionModel = {
        optionSetId: 0,
        optionName: "",
        optionPrice: 0,
        editOptionName: false,
        subOptions: [subOptionModel],
    };
    const [options, setOptions] = useState([optionModel]);
```

I have multiple options in options state, how can I update the state like the option at index 2 and suboption at 1 here is what I tried so for.

```
setOptions(
                options.map((x, index) => {
                    if (index !== optionIndex) return x;
                    x.subOptions.map((subItem, subIndex) => {
                        console.log(subItem);
                        if (subIndex !== subOptionIndex) return subItem;
                        return {
                            ...subItem,
                            text: text
                        };
                    });
                }),
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather use, useReducer hook for this kind of data model. Personally, I find it more clean.

But your problem is that, you are not mutating and returning your subOptions back.

```
setOptions(
  options.map((x, index) => {
      if (index !== optionIndex) return x;
      x.subOptions = x.subOptions.map((subItem, subIndex) => {
          console.log(subItem);
          if (subIndex !== subOptionIndex) return subItem;
          return {
              ...subItem,
              text: text
          };
      });

      return x;
  }),
);
```

Comment: thanks, it works, can you please explain it a bit more maybe it will help someone else :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use an immutability library, such as [immer.js](https://github.com/immerjs/immer). This will allow you to select precisely what you want to update within your state.

This will allow you to modify your options like this:

```js
import produce from "immer"

const newOptions = produce(options, draftOptions => {
    draftOptions[2].subOption[1] = [whatever you want]
})

setOptions(newOptions)
```

Answer (score 0):

following your solution you missed to return in the first `map` if `index === optionIndex`.

```
setOptions((options) => {
  return options.map((x, index) => {
    if (index !== optionIndex) return x;
    return {
      ...x,
      subOptions: x.subOptions.map((subItem, subIndex) => {
        if (subIndex !== subOptionIndex) return subItem;
        return {
          ...subItem,
          text: text
        };
      })
    }
  })
})
```

Otherwise you can use something like `immer.js`